# How to include multiple jar in type from type field in pom dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the following `pom` definition

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.stuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-stuff</artifactId>
        <version>${my-stuff.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

I want to use both `jar` and `test-jar` , is there a way to do that?

Comment: Question not clear. Which jar you want to inclue? Can you elaborate the example?

Comment: You know the intention of a `test-jar`? Apart from that the question is not really clear?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `test-jar` is not a type, but a classifier. You probably want something like:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-stuff</artifactId>
    <version>${my-stuff.version}</version>
    <classifier>test-jar</classifier>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-stuff</artifactId>
    <version>${my-stuff.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```